# How to resolve reference for Azure.Core.dll in VSIX -Visual Studio Extension project?

Tags: c#, azure, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have a piece of code that uploads a file to Azure storage. To do this I had to add `Azure.Core` dll in reference, and dependent assemblies. This code works fine in a standalone WPF application. In the visual studio Extension project, it throws this error-

> Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

My code is referencing to 1.3 version.

Steps that I followed are -

1. Added the dlls as references
2. Added the dllls in the RefAssemblies folder
3. Marked Copy Always and Include in VSIX as true.
4. Mentioned dll version in `app.config`

   ```
     <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
   ```

Why the extension project is looking for 1.2.2 version `dll`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, please install `Azure.Core` version `1.2.2.0`:

```
<dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" culture="neutral" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.2.0" newVersion="1.2.2.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: I can't add 1.2.2.0 as all other projects are referencing a higher version 1.3

Comment: It seems one of the project requires 1.2.2.0, you will have to degrade to this version for all of them.

Comment: Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: Pls degrade version to 1.2.2.0 for all your projects, it should work.